# Java Client/Server over IPv6

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming, ipv6

I am trying to get some experience with Java network programming. So I made a simple text based game. This is how it looks on serverside:

```
    try {
        socket = new ServerSocket(PORT);
        while(true) {
           new ConnectedPlayer(socket.accept()).start();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

And this is the client:

```
System.setProperty("java.net.preferIPv6Addresses","true");
try {
        InetAddress ad = InetAddress.getByName("2a02:8070:b84:6b00:a1d1:30d7:346b:7c14"); 
        socket = new Socket(ad, 9001);
        output = socket.getOutputStream();
        out = new PrintWriter(output);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The address above is the Ipv6 address of the machine running 
the server, I got this one by a website which detects my IP addresses, 
it is different from what I get when I use ipconfig though, tried it with both.
When I tested both on the same machine with localhost, it worked.
However, now I wanted to try it on two different machines, one in a different network. Problem is, my internet provider apparently restricts me to something called "dual stack lite" which means my Server could only be reached over Ipv6 if I understand it correctly. But then, no port forwarding is needed there. When I test it now, it won't connect and gives a timeout after some time. I disabled firewalls on both machines.

Comment: What you should do is forget the lame ISP requirement and get something like a free 6rd tunnel from Hurricane Electric, or one of the other free tunnel providers. This will place you on the IPv6 Internet. You can get a single `/64` subnet, and once that works, you can get a full `/48` network which you can divide into 65,536 `/64` subnets.

Comment: Ron: dslite means full IPv6 with IPv4 provided over a tunnel. The IPv6 part is good, it's the IPv4 part that is "lite" :)

Comment: @SanderSteffann, I understand that, but it is meant to transport IPv4 through an IPv6 tunnel (464). That doesn't sound like what the question needs.

Comment: So is there no solution for simply connecting two IPv6-able devices with ds-lite? I appreciate your idea with the tunnel, but I would like to keep it as simple as possible, for learning purposes. I mean, in theory, my approach should work, right?